# Looking for MKMapView zoom buttons in XCode

Tags: macos, cocoa, button, mkmapview

I know that this question is not directly a programming question, but since this question is tied to XCode there may be some folks that can help me on this one.

I'm looking for the ui element (button, nssegmented control or alike) that is displayed in the native MKMapView for Cocoa Apps.

I tried all different buttons and the NSSegmentedControls, but I couldn't match the display of those buttons added to the MKMapView. Since they are added at runtime (and not visible in the Interface Builder) I don't know how to identify them. Does anyone know how I can achieve a representation of my buttons that is similar to those two?

[image]

Comment: It seems like the UIStepper

Comment: But I'm talking about os x applications, not iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a custom control. You can find the images it uses here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/zoom-minus.tiff
/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/zoom-plus.tiff
/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/zoomControl.tiff
/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/zoomControlMinus.tiff
/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/zoomControlPlus.tiff
```

You'd need to implement a custom `NSView` or `NSControl` and use those resources if you wanted a duplicate control.